# Cross building boost from Cygwin to arm-linux

Tags: linux, boost, cygwin, boost-asio, cross-compiling

I'm trying to build an app that uses boost libraries with Cygwin then later on deploy it on Linux box . I downloaded the latest version of boost, 1.46.1 then followed the instructions here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html.

I'm done with bootstrap and bjam process. When I checked on the stage/lib folder, there are .dll, .dll.a, .a files created. Is these the include libraries needed? I'am expecting to have .so files since it will run on linux but unfortunately .dll's are created.

BTW, I'm using Eclipse IDE with my project.

Here is my test project,

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main(void) 
{
return 0; 
}
```

After compiling, i got linking error:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
/opt/Mx800SDK/vfitc/cross/bin/arm-linux-g++ -L../lib -o'boostTest' ./boostTest.o ./include/boost/fusion/include/adapt_adt_named.o -lpthread -lboost_system -lstdc++
./boostTest.o(.text+0x498): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
./boostTest.o(.text+0x4b0): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
./boostTest.o(.text+0x4c8): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
./boostTest.o(.text+0x4e0): In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
./boostTest.o(.gnu.linkonce.t._ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj+0x60): In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
: undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
```

Any help on how can fix this would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I have changed the title the reflect the cross building you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to cross build for linux-arm, you shall not follow the cygwin instruction.  Do the [cross building](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/tasks/crosscompile.html) instead.

Comment: I tried the following, issue the command: ./bjam target-os=linux, copy the generated .a files to my lib folder, compile, unfortunately I got the same linking error :(

Comment: have you set the ` user-config.jam ` and use `toolset=gcc-arm` accordingly ? You should use the `/opt/Mx800SDK/vfitc/cross/bin/arm-linux-g++` (as shown in your question) as the compiler

Comment: Thank you very much, its working now. I added this line on user-config.jam: using gcc : arm : /opt/Mx800SDK/vfitc/cross/bin/arm-linux-g++ ; then run ./bjam toolset=gcc-arm target-os=linux. Again, thanks, Cheers!